# WPF stackpanel does not show the whole content

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I am using a Combobox to show the contents of two different Lists, the List<Production> productions and the List<Seasons> seasons. Below is the XAML code

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column=" 1" Grid.Row="2">
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ShowProductionsSeasonsNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProductionsSeasons}">
                <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

And this is the code in the viewmodel.

```
public ListCollectionView ShowProductionsSeasonsNames
{
    get
    {
        List<ProductionsSeasonsNames> items = new List<ProductionsSeasonsNames>();

        foreach (var production in this.Productions)
        {
            items.Add(new ProductionsSeasonsNames() { Name = production.DisplayName, Category = "Productions" });
        }
        foreach (var seasons in this.Seasons)
        {
            items.Add(new ProductionsSeasonsNames() { Name = seasons.DisplayName, Category = "Seasons" });
        }

        ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(items);
        lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
        return lcv;
    }
}

public class ProductionsSeasonsNames
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that it **partly** works. Although my productions and seasons lists contain around 100 items each, in the stackpanel only 15 from each list appear. Furthermore when I scroll down or up the focus goes directly to the top of each header without letting me to actually scroll (I am sorry I cant explain this part better). Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this if you try it in a very blank wpf application (which you should do debugging your issue). Must be some other issues with your layout where this is used.

Comment: Is it possible that your DataGrid is a bit messed up? Maybe wrong row-index (start with 0 etc.)? Did you give a specific Height/Width to each row and column? If yes, you should use "*" to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid instead of Stackpanel and set grid height="*" or you can directly put your combobox into Grid.Column=" 1" Grid.Row="2"